# Login to wp-admin "redirect_to" points to wrong URL after migration

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, urls, wp-redirect, site-url

I have a WordPress site hosted on GoDaddy, it's a Windows server, (i have the `web.config` set up). and `.htaccess` correctly configured. The site was working on `example.com/wordpress` , as it was a development test. I moved the site to `example.com` .

I changed the site url and wordpress URL to `example.com` on the database through PhpMyAdmin, and updated the permalink structure.

I also updated all the wp_post 'content' field to change the URL's.

### Issue

When I try to Log In to the admin panel through `example.com/wp-admin`, the URL shows as

```
example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/reauth=1
```

Why could this be happening if both the site url and wordpress url match, and match with the database.

### Additional Notes

This isn't a cache issue (At least not on the browser's side), I have tried different browsers, and I do most of the testing on incognito chrome windows.

I have tried setting `update_option`for both `siteurl` and `home` in `functions.php` and:

```
//wp-config.php
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

I also tried the Relocate Method explained on the Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Do you see correct URLs showing in `Settings > General`?

Comment: Yes. It displays both URLs as the new one. (http://example.com)

Comment: Were you able to solve this case? Last solution would be to reinstall in root.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue. To fix it I had to make some changes to the database. Use phpMyAdmin or just log directly into the database and look at your `wp_options` table. Check the following two fields: `siteurl` and `home`.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name IN ('siteurl', 'home');
```

Make sure these fields hold the correct domain information if not change them and see what happens. In my case the issue was resolved.

Comment: My wordpress instance has those fields set to the proper URL however the html source on login page is still has `<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://localhost/wp-admin/">` at the end ..

Comment: This is how you modify the entries; ```update wp_options set option_value = replace(option_value, "old website url", "new website url");```

Comment: Does not work. Still redirecting to old development link

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve a similar issue using the `wp` [command line tool](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/config/set/).  I had to use the command line tool because I was unable to login to Wordpress admin with my browser.

```
wp @mysitestage config set WP_HOME "https://stage.mysite.com/"
wp @mysitestage config set WP_SITEURL "https://stage.mysite.com/blogdir"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing a login URL change plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/

I needed this security feature as well.

Comment: Adding a description to this comment will help this not look like a spam marketing comment. Also, please explain how this plugin you are recommending solves the issue the OP described.